# How to disable/cancel selection of elements(text inside) generated by @Html.EditorFor or contents of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5.1

How to cancel/disable selecting text:

- generated by `@Html.EditorFor`
- or if not, just any text inside the web application
- or if not, at least text in tables like this one below:

By disabling selecting text I mean block possibility of marking/selectin/choosing text like on image below:

[image]

```
    <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            No.
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CellNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecondaryPhoneNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @noPerson @{noPerson++;}
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CellNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecondaryPhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning btn-xs" })
                @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin")) { <text> |</text>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs" })
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: No clue what you mean by cancel / disable selecting text

Answer (score 0):

From other questions, just add CSS

```
body{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```